# How get a load more button for a li list vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to implement a load more button to my code. I would be able to this in javascript but I can't find a similar way in vue.
This is my vue code. I've tried asking the element with the company id but it's not reactive so I can't just change the style.

```
<main>

    <ul>
      <li v-for="company in companiesdb" :key="company.id" v-bind:id="company.id"  ref="{{company.id}}" style="display: none">
        {{company.name}}<br>
        {{company.email}}
      </li>

    </ul>

</main>
```

this is my failed atempt of doing it in javascript but as I've mentioned before ref is not reactive so I can't do it this way

```
limitView: function (){
   const step = 3;
   do{
     this.numberCompaniesVis ++;
     let li = this.$refs[this.numberCompaniesVis];
     li.style = "display: block";
   }while (this.numberCompaniesVis % 3 != step)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the way you are approaching this problem is a little complex. Instead, you can create a computed variable that will change the number of lists shown.

Here's the code

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(company, index) in companiesLoaded" :key="index">
        {{ company }}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button @click="loadMore">Load</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      companiesdb: [3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1],
      length: 5,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    loadMore() {
      if (this.length > this.companiesdb.length) return;
      this.length = this.length + 3;
    },
  },
  computed: {
    companiesLoaded() {
      return this.companiesdb.slice(0, this.length);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

So instead of loading the list from companiesdb, create a computed function which will return the new array based on companiesdb variable. Then there's the loadMore function which will be executed every time user clicks the button. This function will increase the initial length, so more lists will be shown.

Here's the [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-knuth-d2d3u?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: I'm surprised how easy it was. Thanks you, you've saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 5):

Just use [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) to create subset of main array...

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { 
      companies: [
        { id: 1, name: "Company A" },
        { id: 2, name: "Company B" },
        { id: 3, name: "Company C" },
        { id: 4, name: "Company D" },
        { id: 5, name: "Company E" },
        { id: 6, name: "Company F" },
        { id: 7, name: "Company G" },
        { id: 8, name: "Company H" },
        { id: 9, name: "Company I" },
        { id: 10, name: "Company J" },
      ],
      companiesVisible: 3,
      step: 3,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    visibleCompanies() {
      return this.companies.slice(0, this.companiesVisible)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="company in visibleCompanies" :key="company.id" :id="company.id">
      {{company.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button @click="companiesVisible += step" v-if="companiesVisible < companies.length">Load more...</button>
</div>
```